# Multiple objects types in a single Json trying to read it with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an MVC controller that return 3 object types in a single jSon like this

```
[[objectType1_1][objectType1_2]] 
[[objectType2_1][objectType2_2][objectType2_3]]
[[objectType3_1]]
```

I have a jScript (jQUery) where I'm trying to read it.

```
function cargarListaItems(tcLink , tcPanel) {
 $.post(tcLink, function (datosItems) {
     var Lineas = $(datosItems)[0];
     var Grupos = $(datosItems)[1];
     var Items = $(datosItems)[2];
     for (Linea in Lineas) {
         alert(Linea.Title);
     }
  });
 }
```

The alert allways return undefined for my object, but the property Title is allready defined.

What is the rigth way to read all objects in that jSon array?

EDIT: Typically I use something like this when jSon return only one object type

```
$(data).each(function (object) {
    var Item = $(this)[0];
    alert(Item.Property);
});
```

ANd works fine. but it doesn't work with many objects.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **$ symbol** before the variable

```
$(datosItems)[0] // you are wrapping it as a jQuery object
```

supposed to be

```
datosItems[0]
```

It's the same for the other 2 items..